# H2 Script: Conditional CALL CSVWRITE

Tags: h2

I want to export my H2 database's tables in separate CSV files.

I'm doing it by appending at the end of the .sql file the CSVWRITE methods like that:

```
CALL CSVWRITE ('table.csv', 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID', 'charset=UTF-8');
CALL CSVWRITE ('table1.csv', 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY ID', 'charset=UTF-8');
```

The problem is that sometimes the table might not exist and I'm getting the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "TABLE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID  [42102-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5920)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1430)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:2138)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2133)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1946)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1919)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:463)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:78)
    at org.h2.tools.Csv.write(Csv.java:167)
    at org.h2.expression.Function.getValueWithArgs(Function.java:1556)
    at org.h2.expression.Function.getValue(Function.java:567)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Call.query(Call.java:65)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:202)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:227)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:262)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:192)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:329)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:143)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:70)
```

**How can I check if the table exists before I call the CSVWRITE?**

Thank you!